# Is it possible to make trim in a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, trim

I'd like to count all the inputs in my form which are empty. With empty I mean that its value is empty after trimming its value (if the user insert whitespaces its empty as well).
This jquery count them, but it doesn't include the trimming:

```
$(':text').filter('[value=""]').length
```

Has something jquery which can be used to trim in the selector?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(':text').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 10):

While [the `.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in @Domenic's answer is a good approach, I'd implement it a little differently.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/mjuyk/

```
$('input:text').filter(function () {
    return !$.trim(this.value);
});
```

- You should specify `input:text`. Otherwise jQuery needs to observe *every* element in the DOM to see if it is `type='text'`. ([See the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/))
- Because these are text inputs, it is quicker to use `this.value` than `$(this).val()`.
- No need to get the `length` property since an empty string is falsey. So just use the `!` operator.

---

Or you could use the inverse of `.filter()`, which is [the `.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/mjuyk/1/

```
$('input:text').not(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value);
});
```

---

Also, you can create a custom selector like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/mjuyk/2/

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
   novalue: function(elem, i, attr){
      return !$.trim(elem.value);
   }
});

$('input:text:novalue')
```