# css selector for combined elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This jQuery selector tries to select all the html elements with the class `required` which works fine, I want to also add to all html input elements with their values trimmed not equal to blank.

```
$('.required').each(function () {//do stuff}) // works fine
```

my imagination:

```
$('.required, input:text[value.trim() != '']').each(function () {//do stuff})
```

How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: I'd say that this is a dupe - [Is it possible to make trim in a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270727/is-it-possible-to-make-trim-in-a-selector)

Comment: I won't put this as an answer since I'm not sure if that is "encouraged". But I wrote a small npm package that would do what you are trying to do. Are you using npm?

Comment: @KevBot Yes I am using npm.

Comment: The package is called [`query-by-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-by-regex). If you wanted to get an input of type text, with a css class required and an input that is not all whitespace, you could do this:

`QueryByRegex.all(/(?=.*?type="text")(?=.*?value="\S*")(?=.*?class=".*required.*")/)`

They are lookaheads since the order of attributes can be any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to iterate over each item, check against the value after trimming it, then do the magic:

```js
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
  if ($.trim(this.value).length) {
    // do stuff
    $(this).addClass('has-content');
  }
});
```

```css
.has-content {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test" />
<input type="text" value=" " />
<input type="text" value="" />
```